# View all updated files in all directories in StarTeam

Tags: version-control, starteam

I have a StarTeam project. It has several directories. When I commit changes I don't want to have to search all the directories myself to find changed files.

How can I see all changed files in all directories in one list without searching myself?

I am using StarTeam 2009.

P.S. I come from Mercurial and TortoiseHg so it seems incredible to me that I can't seem to be able to do this easily in StarTeam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Left side slect the root node of the tree then select the filter "All File By Status" and the short button "All descendant" beside!
With the context Menu from the Status Field you can group your Results.

[image]

Georg

Comment: You can save the settings for the selectetd Filter, you made for the table, over the context menu "Save Current Settings ..."!